# How can I rearrange the functions to combine a with statement with a decorator for Flask?

Tags: python, session, flask

I've built a custom session handler which stores the important bits in a database, and just keeps the ID in the default Flask session (which is an encrypted cookie). Each time a page loads, the session data is read (or created with a new ID), then on exit the session is saved to the database. I basically followed the idea of PHP sessions, but saved it in the database instead of as a file.

I've set it up with `__enter__` and `__exit__` to work like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    with SessionHandler(mysql) as session:

        #Get a new session ID but keep the session data
        session.regenerate()

        #Add 1 to session variable
        try:
            session['count'] += 1
        except KeyError:
            session['count'] = 1

        #Other code here
```

I was thinking of just manually doing the login (like redirect to page if user is not logged in), but I came across the `@login_required` and it seems a decent way of doing things.

Here's one of the default implementations of it:

```
def login_required(function_to_protect):
    @wraps(function_to_protect)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        user_id = session.get('user_id')
        if user_id:
            user = database.get(user_id)
            if user:
                # Success!
                return function_to_protect(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                flash("Session exists, but user does not exist (anymore)")
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            flash("Please log in")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/')
@login_required
def main():
    return 'you are logged in'
```

However, if I was to link that with my own session variables, I'd have to do another database lookup on the session for every page.

Is there a way I could combine both methods, so that I can access the session data in a decorator without reading from the database again? Also it'd be a bonus if I could streamline the `with SessionManager(mysql) as session` part, as every function will now have 2 levels of indentation, and I'm not quite sure if there's a way around that.

If it's at all useful, here's the class (still WIP):

```
class SessionManager(object):
    def __init__(self, db_connection):
        self.sql = db_connection.sql

    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            session_id = session['sid']
            hash = quick_hash(session_id)
            session_data = self.sql('SELECT data_pickle, last_activity FROM temporary_storage WHERE id = %s', hash)
            if session_data and session_data[0][1] > time.time() - SESSION_TIMEOUT:
                self.hash = hash
                self.data = cPickle.loads(session_data[0][0])
                self._new_id = False
                return self
            else:
                raise KeyError
        except KeyError:
            self.new()
            return self

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data[item]

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self.data[item] = value

    def get(self, item, default):
        return self.data.get(item, default)

    def new(self):
        self.regenerate()
        self.data = {}

    def regenerate(self):
        while True:
            session_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
            hash = quick_hash(session_id)
            if not self.sql('SELECT count(*) FROM temporary_storage WHERE id = %s', hash):
                session['sid'] = session_id
                self.hash = hash
                self._new_id = True
                return session_id

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        data = cPickle.dumps(self.data)
        if self._new_id:
            self.sql('INSERT INTO temporary_storage (id, data_pickle, last_activity) VALUES(%s, %s, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))', self.hash, data)
        else:
            self.sql('UPDATE temporary_storage SET data_pickle = %s, last_activity = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) WHERE id = %s', data, self.hash)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a decorator that takes an argument like this:

```
def with_session_handler(driver):
    def decorator(func_to_wrap):
        @wraps(func_to_wrap)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with SessionHandler(driver) as session:
                return func_to_wrap(*args, **kwargs, session=session)
        return wrapper
return decorator
```

The outermost function creates the decorator as a closure which is aware of the `driver` object. It's visible all the way down into the `wrapper` function, where you can use it in a `with` statement when calling the wrapped function.

Then to use it:

```
@app.route('/')
@with_session_handler(mysql)
def main(session):
    #Get a new session ID but keep the session data
    session.regenerate()

    #Add 1 to session variable
    try:
        session['count'] += 1
    except KeyError:
        session['count'] = 1

    #Other code here
```

Comment: Thanks, so will doing it this way also call `SessionHandler.__exit__` on the exit of `main`, and not the exit of `with_session_handler`? Also, would the login functionality be put inside `with_session_handler`? Sorry gotta go shortly so can't test out until later :)

Comment: Actually yeah I understand what you're doing, the require login part could be passed in as a variable and handled within that. Thanks a bunch :)  I'll leave it up while I'm gone though just to see if there's any other potential alternatives

Comment: For the record, `func_to_wrap(*args, **kwargs, session=session)` should start with session or it complains about syntax, the rest works great though, and the login part was quite easy to mix in.